# AngularJS: ng-repeat, filter and index

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, coffeescript

Sorry for my language skills, hope You understand all.

I have a problem with ng-repeat and filter data. 
Im using $index, to get some data from ng-repeat data.
For example, i have 20 elements. when i click on third, then index is 3, and application display me more data about third element.
Now, when i use filter, it doesnt work well, becouse when i filter last element, and click on it, index is 0 and application show me more data about first element.
What i want to do, is when i filter,for example, 15th element and when i click on it, i get more data about 15th element, not first.

HTML:

```
.panel-body ng-repeat=("restaurant in restaurants | filter:search") ng-click="addRestaurant($index);"
                a aria-expanded="true" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" style="font-size: 18px;" 
                  i.fa.fa-chevron-right.pull-right.text-muted ng-show="$index == index"
                  | {{restaurant.name}}
```

JS SCRIPT:

```
$scope.addRestaurant = (index) ->
  $scope.index = index
  $scope.selectedRestaurant = $scope.restaurants[$scope.index].id
```

Comment: why not just send the restaurant object to the function `ng-click="addRestaurant(restaurant)` and then use it?

Comment: Where is the search filter defined? Why do you use the same element for your list and details view? What HTML (template?) syntax is this?

Comment: @war1oc thanks, now i send restaurant object. i made couple change in function, and work well now!

Comment: You could also pass just the id of selected restaurant and use that to get your data with a find function over the array that contains the list.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using **$index**? You can use just the **iteration item**

**Use**

```
$scope.addRestaurant = (restaurant)...
...
ng-repeat=("restaurant in restaurants | filter:search") ng-click="addRestaurant(restaurant);"
```

**not with $index**

in **addRestaurant** function you already have **clicked restaurant**